# Setting up Storm on Google Cloud

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, apache-storm

I was wondering if there's been any work on setting up Apache Storm on Google Compute Engine. I have been using this blog (http://datadventures.ghost.io/2013/12/29/deploying-storm-on-gce/) but I can't seem to get my nimbus instance setup to work properly.

The blog states that to check if my nimbus instance is functioning, I should have a look at the Nimbus Web UI. However, I can't seem to display the UI on my browser. I have made the necessary changes in the storm.yaml file.

My storm.yaml file looks like :

```
storm.zookeeper.servers:
     - "test-1"
 ui.port : 8080
 nimbus.host: "nimbus"
 nimbus.childopts: "-Xmx1024m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
 ui.childopts: "-Xmx768m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
 supervisor.childopts: "-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
 worker.childopts: "-Xmx768m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
 storm.local.dir: "/app/storm"
```

I checked my nimbus.log file and I see the following:

```
2016-10-26 18:57:27 b.s.d.nimbus [INFO] Starting Nimbus with conf {"dev.zookeeper.path" "/tmp/dev-storm-zookeeper", "topology.tick.tuple.freq.secs" nil, "topolo$
2016-10-26 18:57:27 b.s.d.nimbus [INFO] Using default scheduler
2016-10-26 18:57:27 c.n.c.f.i.CuratorFrameworkImpl [INFO] Starting
2016-10-26 18:57:27 o.a.z.ZooKeeper [INFO] Initiating client connection, connectString=test-1:2181 sessionTimeout=20000 watcher=com.netflix.curator.ConnectionSt$
2016-10-26 18:57:27 o.a.z.ClientCnxn [INFO] Opening socket connection to server test-1/10.142.0.9:2181
2016-10-26 18:57:27 o.a.z.ClientCnxn [INFO] Socket connection established to test-1/10.142.0.9:2181, initiating session
2016-10-26 18:57:27 o.a.z.ClientCnxn [INFO] Session establishment complete on server test-1/10.142.0.9:2181, sessionid = 0x157fc2e050f0008, negotiated timeout =$
2016-10-26 18:57:27 b.s.zookeeper [INFO] Zookeeper state update: :connected:none
2016-10-26 18:57:27 o.a.z.ClientCnxn [INFO] EventThread shut down
2016-10-26 18:57:27 o.a.z.ZooKeeper [INFO] Session: 0x157fc2e050f0008 closed
2016-10-26 18:57:27 c.n.c.f.i.CuratorFrameworkImpl [INFO] Starting
2016-10-26 18:57:27 o.a.z.ZooKeeper [INFO] Initiating client connection, connectString=test-1:2181/storm sessionTimeout=20000 watcher=com.netflix.curator.Connec$
2016-10-26 18:57:27 o.a.z.ClientCnxn [INFO] Opening socket connection to server test-1/10.142.0.9:2181
2016-10-26 18:57:27 o.a.z.ClientCnxn [INFO] Socket connection established to test-1/10.142.0.9:2181, initiating session
2016-10-26 18:57:27 o.a.z.ClientCnxn [INFO] Session establishment complete on server test-1/10.142.0.9:2181, sessionid = 0x157fc2e050f0009, negotiated timeout =$
2016-10-26 18:57:27 b.s.d.nimbus [INFO] Starting Nimbus server...
```

This shows that my nimbus instance connects with the zookeeper. However, I am stumped as to how to access the UI. I try to access it using:

```
http://[Public IP of Nimbus GCP Instance]:8080
```

I would really appreciate any help. I haven't come across anything with respect to building storm over google compute engine.I'm a relative new comer to Storm.

Thanks

Edit:

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules list | grep 8080
```

```
nimbusui  default  0.0.0.0/0  udp:8080,tcp:8080
```

On the nimbus instance, I tried:

```
netstat -l 8080
```

```
    Active Internet connections (only servers)
    Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
    tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN     
    tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN     
    udp        0      0 *:42924                 *:*                                
    udp        0      0 *:bootpc                *:*                                
    udp        0      0 nimbus.c.ecg-sandbo:ntp *:*                                
    udp        0      0 localhost:ntp           *:*                                
    udp        0      0 *:ntp                   *:*                                
    udp6       0      0 [::]:14994              [::]:*                             
    udp6       0      0 fe80::4001:aff:fe8e:ntp [::]:*                             
    udp6       0      0 ip6-localhost:ntp       [::]:*                             
    udp6       0      0 [::]:ntp                [::]:*                             
    Active UNIX domain sockets (only servers)
    Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   Path
    unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     10687    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
    unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     11147    /var/run/acpid.socket
    unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8751     @/com/ubuntu/upstart
    unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     9447     /run/udev/control
```

I also checked ui.log :

```
2016-10-27 18:14:52 o.m.log [INFO] Logging to Logger[org.mortbay.log] via org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog
2016-10-27 18:14:52 o.m.log [INFO] jetty-6.1.26
2016-10-27 18:14:52 o.m.log [INFO] Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
```

Comment: 1- Have you checked that the application is listening on port 8080? i.e ¨netstat --listen¨

2- What is the output for the Google Firewall rules on port 8080? I.e 
¨ gcloud compute  firewall-rules list | grep 8080¨

Comment: Thank you. Please see the edit.

Comment: netstat output shows that there is no service listening on port 8080. According to [this link](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-multi-node-storm-cluster/#start-the-storm-ui-daemon-manually) the UI is optional. I would try to start the daemon manually on the master node.